# How to solve the `Object doesn't support #inspect` error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inspect

I am using rails v3.2.2 and I get a strange error when I try to load associated records.

The following is the Terminal input/output I get:

```
1.9.2-p318 :011 > Category.first
=> #<Category id: 1, ...>

1.9.2-p318 :013 > Category.first.articles
  Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `articles`.* FROM `articles` LIMIT 1
(Object doesn't support #inspect)

1.9.2-p318 :014 > Category.first.articles.first
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `scoped' for Category::Article:Module
    from /<USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:123:in `target_scope'
    from /<USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/through_association.rb:15:in `target_scope'
    from /<USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:87:in `scoped'
    from /<USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:569:in `first_or_last'
    from /<USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:101:in `first'
    from /<USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `first'
    from (irb):14
    from /<USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /<USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /<USER_PATH>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

In my `Category` model I have:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_relationships,
    :class_name  => 'Category::Article::ArticleRelationship',
    :foreign_key => 'category_id'

  has_many :articles,
    :through     => :article_relationships,
    :source      => :article
end
```

In my `Category::Article::ArticleRelationship` I have:

```
class Category::Article::ArticleRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article,
    :class_name    => 'Article',
    :foreign_key   => 'article_id'
end
```

**How to solve the problem related to `Object doesn't support #inspect`?**

---

*Note*: In the same `Category` model I have a similar statement like for `Category::Article::ArticleRelationship` (it is related to an `User` class through a `Category::UserRelationship` class) and it does not cause problems.

Comment: Did you `require 'article'` before trying to inspect them?

Comment: @sarnold - No, I do not `require 'article'` at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two constants called `Article` on your app. One is your active record class, top level constant. The other is the module 
`Category::Article`.

When you do `belongs_to :article`, it would seem that rails starts looking for an `Article` constant in the class the belongs_to is called from so it is finding the wrong one. This causes all sorts of mess, since you obviously can't use an activerecord class and a module interchangeably

Setting `:class_name => '::Article'` forces the top level `Article` class to be found instead.

Comment: Is it "dangerous" to have a class and a module stated with the same name? If so, what could be a better way to proceed?

Comment: Anyway, I just realized that I have two *classes* (one of which namespaced) that could fit in what you said: `Category` and `Category::Article`.

Comment: Not dangerous, you'll just need to disambiguate sometimes.

Comment: I opened a related question since I have some problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255587/how-to-solve-the-nameerror-uninitialized-constant-when-using-namespaced-classe

Answer (score 5):

If are using rails 4, the problem came from protected_attributes gem, u need to upgrade the gem version 1.0.3 to 1.0.5, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved by stating the following in my `Category::Article::ArticleRelationship`:

```
class Category::Article::ArticleRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article,
    :class_name    => '::Article', # note I added '::'
    :foreign_key   => 'article_id'
end
```

*but I didn't understand why?*