# Trouble on solving the "NameError uninitialized constant" when using namespaced classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, constants

I am using rails v3.2.2. I have two classes stated like the following:

```
# app/models/article/category/article_relationship.rb
class Article::Category::ArticleRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

# app/models/comment/category/article_relationship.rb
class Comment::Category::ArticleRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

# app/models/article/category.rb
class Article::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

# app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

If in my view file I state

```
::Article::Category::ArticleRelationship
# or
Article::Category::ArticleRelationship
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError
uninitialized constant Category::ArticleRelationship
```

**How can I solve the problem?**

---

**UPDATE**

I discovered the problem occurs "mostly" when I state at the same time more than one namespaced class in the same file like, for example:

```
::Article::Category::ArticleRelationship
::Article::Category
# or
::Comment::Category::ArticleRelationship
::Article::Category
# or
::Article::Category
::Article::Category::ArticleRelationship
# or
::Article::Category::ArticleRelationship
Article::Category
# or
Article::Category::ArticleRelationship
::Article::Category
# or
::Article::Category::ArticleRelationship
::Article
# or
::Article
::Comment::Category::ArticleRelationship
# or
...
```

and it seems to happen *randomly!*

---

*Note*: This question is "inspired" by the answer of @Frederick Cheung to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255150/how-to-solve-the-object-doesnt-support-inspect-error/10255357).

Comment: Where are all these classes (ie in which files)?

Comment: @Frederick Cheung - I updated the question with some more information.

Comment: @Frederick Cheung - I discover some more and I updated the question as well.

Comment: At first glance I don't see anything obvious wrong with your code, but why are you namespacing your classes three deep? With a parallel structure between articles and comments it seems unlikely that your approach is very DRY. Share a little more about what you're trying to accomplish and maybe we can help you find a better way to do it, thus avoiding your bug by refactoring out of the need to call classes that way.

Comment: @Andrew - I am namespacing classes three deep because I need *different* relationships with categories (`Category::ArticleRelationship`) for more than one class that behaves *differently*. *What of important I have to share?*